# Why does mstest hang when awaiting in a WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext?

Tags: winforms, async-await, mstest

I have a custom Windows Forms control that is covered with MSTest unit tests.  I added an async method to this class that I need to cover as well but the new test always times out.

After some experimentation I've reduced the problem down to just a control creation and an await.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestMethod1()
{
    Control c = new Control();
    await Task.Delay(1);
}
```

I noticed that the test begins with the `SynchronizationContext.Current` set to `null`, then as soon as the control is created it changes to a `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`.  If I force the synchronization context back to `null`, then the test will pass.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestMethod1()
{
    Control c = new Control();
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);
    await Task.Delay(1);
}
```

Is there any way to use await from a `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` without blocking?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows Forms controls assume that they are running inside a Windows Forms application, which is not the case for unit tests. That is why your unit test is hanging.

To be more specific, WinForms controls install a `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` that delegates work to the Win32 message loop inside `Application.Run`. So, your `async` method sees the context and queues its continuation to that message loop. However, there is no actual message loop because your unit test doesn't ever call `Application.Run`.

The best solution IMO is to use an MVVM pattern where you do not test UI elements outside of a UI application, so you never run into this situation (in MVVM, you unit test the *logical* UI but not the *literal* UI). With an MVVM approach your code would look like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestMethod1()
{
  ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
  await vm.MethodAsync();
}
```

But if you do want to unit test the actual UI elements, you can use a type like the [Windows Forms Context](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncCTPUtil/blob/master/AsyncTestUtilities/WindowsFormsContext.cs) that was included in the Async CTP:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestMethod1()
{
    await WindowsFormsContext.Run(async () =>
    {
        Control c = new Control();
        await Task.Delay(1);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and great advice on using MVVM.  We are trying to move our application towards MVVM, but since there is so much existing code it is a long process.  In the meantime the WindowsFormsContext works great!